# Finding the number of elements of particular order in the symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I know how to find the order of element in any group $G$, for example the order of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is $5$ as $2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = [10]_5 = 0 0$, which is the identity in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

But, how to calculate number of element of particular order in symmetric group $S_n$?

I know how to calculate order of an element in $S_n$, for example in $S_5$, $(123)(45)$ has an order $6$. But how to calculate easily number of such elements? That is, how to calculate number of elements order $5$, number of elements of order $4$ in $S_5$? Is there is any easy formula? Also is there is any formula to calculate the number of elements of particular order in the alternating group $A_n$ as well?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311680/finding-the-number-of-elements-of-order-two-in-the-symmetric-group-s-4

Comment: please, i need more than that.

Comment: What more do you need beyond that? That is, what are you stuck on?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's not a simple formula known for this, and certain aspects of the question are the subject of ongoing research.  For example, [this paper](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma561/notes/symorder.pdf) summarizes some research that has been done on the maximum possible order for an element of $S_n$.

In general, the way to find the number of elements of order $k$ in $S_n$ is:

1. Determine all possible cycle types for an element of order $k$, and then
2. Determine the number of elements having each of these cycle types.

For step (1), you're just looking for all possible ways to partition $n$ into cycles so that the least common multiple of the cycle lengths is $k$.  For example, if permutation has order six, then all the cycles must have length $1$, $2$, $3$, or $6$, with either at least one $6$-cycle or one cycle each of lengths $2$ and $3$.  So if we want to count the number of permutations of order six in $S_8$, the possibilities are

- One $6$-cycle, one $2$-cycle,
- One $6$-cycle, two $1$-cycles,
- Two $3$-cycles, one $2$-cycle,
- One $3$-cycle, two $2$-cycles, and one $1$-cycle, or
- One $3$-cycle, one $2$-cycle, and three $1$-cycles.

Step (2) is easy once you figure out step (1).  In particular, the number of permutations in $S_n$ with a given cycle structure is
$$
\frac{n!}{\prod_{d=1}^n (c_d)!\,d^{c_d}}
$$
where $c_d$ denotes the number of cycles of length $d$.  For example, the number of elements of $S_{20}$ having four $1$-cycles, five $2$-cycles, and two $3$-cycles is
$$
\frac{20!}{(4!\cdot 1^4)(5!\cdot 2^5)(2!\cdot 3^2)} \;=\; 1\text{,}466\text{,}593\text{,}128\text{,}000.
$$
The following table shows the number of elements of each order in $S_2$ through $S_8$.
$$
\begin{array}{crrrrrrrrrrr}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 10 & 12 & 15 \\
\hline
S_2 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & -\\
S_3 & 1 & 3 & 2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
S_4 & 1 & 9 & 8 & 6 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
S_5 & 1 & 25 & 20 & 30 & 24 & 20 & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
S_6 & 1 & 75 & 80 & 180 & 144 & 240 & - & - & - & - & - \\
S_7 & 1 & 231 & 350 & 840 & 504 & 1470 & 720 & - & 504 & 420 & - \\
S_8 & 1 & 763 & 1232 & 5460 & 1344 & 10640 & 5760 & 5040 & 4032 & 3360 & 2688
\end{array}
$$
This table is entry [A057731](https://oeis.org/A057731) at OEIS.

Comment: Could you please help me by posting a derivation of the formula?

Answer (score 3):

Order is determined by the cycle structure. By that I mean a transposition has order $2$, a $3$-cycle has order $3$, etc. If $\sigma_1 \dots \sigma_t$ are disjoint cycles of order $r_1 \dots r_t$ then the order of $\sigma_1 \dots \sigma_t$ is $\textrm{lcm}(r_1 \dots r_t)$. So this is more of a combinatorial problem: look at each cycle structure and compute the possible permutations. Be careful of double counting. For $A_n$ you can simply restrict yourself to the even permutations.

If you're looking for an explicit way to produce elements of a given order, recall that cycle structure, thereby order, is preserved under conjugation. So you can compute all the conjugacy classes of elements of a given order (this is easy for small $n$, tedious for a large $n$).

Answer (score 3):

The facts below help you to find how many elements have a given order, but the combinatorial details are probably messy; I don't there is a simple formula.

- Every permutation is a product of disjoint cycles, which is unique except for order.
- The order of a product of disjoint cycles is the lcm of their orders.
- The order of a permutation is determined by its cycle structure, which is the list of the orders of its disjoint cycles.
- The number of possible cycle structures is the same as the number of the partitions of $n$.
- The possible cycle structures corresponds to the conjugacy classes in $S_n$.