# Finding the number of elements of order 7 in $S_9$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm trying to find how many elements in $S_9$  have order $7$. 
 
 Using the fact the order of $g$ is the lowest common multiple of the length of its disjoint cycles, the only combination of cycles possible is: one of length $7$, and two of length $1$. 
 
 What I'm having trouble with is finding how many $g$ ϵ $S_9$ are in this form. 
 
 My logic would be you would have $9$ options to pick for the "$1$ cycle" and then $8$ options for the next "$1$ cycle" and for the "$7$ cycle" there would be $6!$ options as each one cannot map to the starting elements. 
 
 So the number of elements in $S_9$ that have order $7$ would be $9*8*6! =51840$ yet I'm not sure this is correct because I have seen someone post a general formula for a similar problem (link below) that does not yield the same answer (It actually gives half of my answer, $25920$), can someone please point out what I'm missing? 
 
 Thanks. 
 
 [Finding the number of elements of particular order in the symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340297/finding-the-number-of-elements-of-particular-order-in-the-symmetric-group?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the two $1$-cycles doesn‘t matter, so you need to divide by $2!=2$.