# How many elements in $S_4$ (the symmetric group of (1,2,3,4)) have order 6?

Tags: probability

The question is:
How many elements in $S_4$ (the symmetric group of  (1,2,3,4)) have order 6?

How can I think here?

Comment: categorize the elements in $S_4$ with respect to their cycle structure.

Comment: This has been shown many times here. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340297/finding-the-number-of-elements-of-particular-order-in-the-symmetric-group) for solving this in general. Also, please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Consider the classical **decomposition into disjoint cycles** : there are 3 types $(abcd), (a)(bcd),(ab)(cd)$ ; take exponents 2 or 3 on each , it will be difficult to find an order 6 !

Comment: Using the Landau function $g(n)$ we have $g(4)=4$, so the maximal order of an element in $S_4$ is $4$. Hence $6$ is impossible. See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/maximal-order-of-an-element-in-a-symmetric-group).

Comment: @JeanMarie $4$ types, don't forget the identity.

Comment: @jjagmath You are right !

Comment: @JeanMarie Actually $5$. There's also $(ab)(c)(d)$

Comment: @jjagmath I am not well awaked this morning !

Comment: I used the method proposed and got 4 but that is wrong. 5 is also wrong answer.

Comment: We are talking about the posible possible types of the decomposition into disjoint cycles  (there are $5$) which you're supposed to use to find the number of elements of order $6$ which are *zero*.